# How to fix the code that should highlight selected area with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What I want to achieve is to make "select to inspect" type of functionality, just like the browsers have. It should only have the functionality of creating a temporary element that will be overlayed over the element that my mouse is hovering on.

I have created a screencast to show you what it should be like, and what I currently have.

[Link to video on google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lvfDtyf3UAguPgENeq4Xfr-wxLLkGX_H/view?usp=sharing)

My code

```
function create_div(){
  let style = `
 background-color: rgba(130, 180, 230, 0.5);
 outline: solid 1px #0F4D9A;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 z-index: 999999;
`
  let e = document.createElement('DIV')
  e.setAttribute('id', 'tester')
  e.setAttribute('style', style)
  document.body.appendChild( e )
}
create_div()


$( "body" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
  $( '#tester' ).css({'display' : 'none'})
  let target = $( event.target )
  $( '#tester' ).css({'display' : 'block', "width": target.width(),
 'height': target .height(), 'top' : target .offset().top,
 'left' : target .offset().left});
})
```

This is my code written with jQuery
It creates a DIV on the page and then, on `mousemove` event, I set its values (height, width, and the position)
to be the same as the element that I am hovering on. But what I get is some glitchy windows when I hover over.

What am I missing here?

Comment: because you are hovering on top of the element that you added....

Comment: @epascarello But, I am removing it with `$( '#tester' ).css({'display' : 'none'})

Comment: Hi @Vlada, your video requires access to view. On that note, try adding `pointer-events: none` to your styles. Seems to remove the glitchiness.

Comment: @Jack Hey, I have changed the link, now it should be viewable

Comment: Thanks @Vlada, I can see the video. Did you try applying the `pointer-events: none` to your `style` block?

Comment: @Jack Yes, that seems to be what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @AndreiGheorghiu, thanks for the insight. Can you tell me, what are the limitations of `pointer-events`? Why should I avoid it?

Comment: On second thought, `pointer-events` makes sense. You want to allow the pointer to interfere with the page naturally.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `pointer-events: none;` to the `#tester`'s CSS - it will make DIV transparent for mouse events. It is to unglitch from mouseover-ing

To kill another possible glitch-source, let's just save somewhere last target you have processed, so it will be no need to resize/redraw `#tester` again.

It will result in:

```
function create_div(){
    $("body").append(
        $("<div id=\"tester\"></div>").css({
            "background-color": "rgba(130, 180, 230, 0.5)",
            "outline": "solid 1px #0F4D9A",
            "box-sizing": "border-box",
            "position": "absolute",
            "display": "block",
            "z-index": "999999",
            "pointer-events": "none"
        })
     );
}

$(document).ready(create_div);

$("body").mousemove(function( event ) {
    let target = $(event.target)
    if (target.length === 0){
        $("#tester").css({
            "display" : "none"
        });
        $("#tester").data("target", null);
    }else if(
        $("#tester").data("target") === null || 
        $("#tester").data("target") !== target 
    ){
        $("#tester").data("target", target);
        $("#tester").css({
            "display" : "block", 
            "width"   : target.width(),
            "height"  : target.height(), 
            "top"     : target.offset().top,
            "left"    : target.offset().left
        });
    }
    // else {leave #tester with no changes}
});
```